# set focus on search textbox instead of address bar on google-chrome-extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, focus, setfocus

I've tried to create a simple google-chrome-extension for a custom new tab.
I've used two files to do it:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "focus",
  "version": "0.2",
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "new.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

new.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setFocus()
{
document.getElementById("fname").focus();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="setFocus()">
<form>
Search: <input type="text" id="fname" size="30"><br>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

After I install those files as a chrome-extension I open a new tab.
It works but the focus is on address bar (omnibox) and NOT on search textbox.

How can I set the focus on search textbox?

thanks

Comment: You can't override the browser.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Any errors in the console? There are no errors with the script itself. (http://jsfiddle.net/CUqZm/)